# Unwanted newline when appending to f in array.each do |f|

Tags: ruby

Why does the following piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
replacements = ['A1', 'E1', 'I1', 'Y1', 'U1', 'O2', 'O1', 'Ae', 'D1', 'Th', 'o1', 'u1', 'y1', 'ae', 'a1', 'i1', 'th', 'd1', 'o2']
contentsArray = File.readlines(ARGV[0])
wordArray = []
existingWords = []
contentsArray.each do |i|
  i.capitalize!
  i<<"_setn.caf"
  open("hljodsetn_final", "a") do |f|
    puts i
  end
end
```

Produce this sort of output

```
someString1 
_setn.caf
someString2 
_setn.caf
someString1
_setn.caf
```

Where I would expect

```
someString1_setn.caf
someString2_setn.caf
someString3_setn.caf
```

When I try similar things directly such as `array.each do |f|` and append `"someString"` to `f` via `f<<"someString"` it seems to work perfectly but not in this instance of reading from file capitalizing each one and then appending this string starting with `"_"`.

Would really appreciate some insights!

Comment: Naming convention advice: `contentsArray` -> `contents`, `wordArray` -> `words`, `existingWords` -> `existing_words`

Comment: I assume this isn't a complete snippet because of the unused variables, but if you are opening the same file multiple times in a loop, you should move it outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just threw this together ad hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read lines from a file. Each line ends with a newline, naturally. And you append your text after it.

```
"someString1\n" << "_setn.caf" # => "someString1\n_setn.caf"
```

You can get rid of newlines like this, for example:

```
contentsArray = File.readlines(ARGV[0]).map(&:chomp)
```

Comment: Not *Rubyish* name - `contentsArray`.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The File.readlines creates an array of lines, the lines all end in newline (which is how it knows where to identify the end of line).

```
i.capitalize!.chomp!
```

That will get rid of the newline.

Comment: It does not append anything. Newlines just are there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, you're right!  I'll amend the answer.